# Which JDK/JRE is a given Eclipse project using?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a current version of Eclipse (4.5.2) and I've got several JDKs and JREs installed. How do I determine which specific JDK/JRE a given project is using?

The reason I ask is that I'm trying to figure out which logging.properties file to edit to make my logging work the way I want it.

I used -version as a VM argument in my project and it told me:
java version "1.8.0_74"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_74-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.74-b02, mixed mode)

Unfortunately, I have both a JDK and a JRE at that level so I'm not sure which one it is using in this project. Can anyone enlighten me?

The JRE system library in my project says [Java1.8SE] in Package Explorer but the individual jars in that library all look like this:
rt.jar C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib 
which suggests that I have a 1.7 jre.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: I've solved this myself, rather unexpectedly. I noticed that the Java Console indicated C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib in the header line at the top of the display. I tried editing the logging.properties file in *that* directory and finally got a log file generated. I'd still be interested in other methods of determining the same thing. Also, I'm still confused by how my project can call for Java 1.8 conformance, claim that the JRE library is Java1.8SE yet apparently go into a completely different directory to get a Java 1.7 JRE.  I'm very confused....

Comment: The JRE (or other execution environment) in a Debug or Run Configuration (as applicable) can be different from the *project* JRE; check the 'JRE' tab to the right of the one for 'Arguments'

Answer (score 0):

Create a new class with a new `main`. Your program will then print your version.

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.version"));
```

You can also do this by right-clicking on the JRE System Library at the bottom of the project and then clicking 'Configure Build Path' under 'Build Path'. Then look at 'Libraries'. This tells you what your JRE System Library is.